# AWS SDK for iOS: problems with conversion from Swift 2 to Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, swift3, code-conversion

I have downloaded the **AWS SDK** for iOS examples and opened them in XCode 8. Unfortunately there were lots of compiler errors due to the conversion from Swift 3. I fixed most of these but some functions still need fixing.

I am surprised that there is no official example from Amazon using Swift 3.

- What has been your approach?
- Did you go on fixing all these errors or has any of you found an example for Swift 3?

I am particularly interested in this sub-part of the repository:
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-ios-samples/tree/master/S3TransferUtility-Sample/Swift/

**EDIT:**

I am testing the Objective-C version of the project as a proof of concept. 
Unfortunately when I run it I get the following error:

```
Connection = "keep-alive";
"Content-Length" = 451;
"Content-Type" = "application/x-amz-json-1.1";
Date = "Fri, 13 Jan 2017 15:59:58 GMT";
"x-amzn-ErrorMessage" = "2 validation errors detected: Value 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:99999999999:userpool/eu-west-1_XXXXXXXXX' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must have length less than or equal to 55; Value 'arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-west-1:99999999999:userpool/eu-west-1_XXXXXXXXX' at 'identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must satisfy regular expression pattern
```

It puzzles me as I thought I had configured the identity pool correctly in the Info.plist file.

See below (the details of the pool are hidden partially, but they are the same as the ones that the Database administrator gave me).

[image]

Any ideas of why this is happening?

Literal message says that **identityPoolId' failed to satisfy constraint** but I am not convinced about this. It could be that there is some configuration missing on the server side.

Unfortunately the documentation is not complete and I am a bit lost at the moment (feels like a waste of time).

Comment: yes there is no good document available worst documentations provided by amazon. We have to walk alone and have to solve these errors. I have solved previously these type of errors in s3:(

Comment: I have added an EDIT.. would you be able to double check if u encountered a similar problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your identity pool id should be in a format like..
`eu-west-1:xxxxxxxxxx`

Comment: Thanks. I have tried with that format but doesn't work.. the screenshot is deceiving (I put incorrect details there to protect the real id)

Comment: What is the format you tried with? Because the validation error is that the IdentityPoolID you specified is in the wrong format.